# Change setting of Dash To Dock using terminal

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, dock

I want to change one setting of Dash to Dock extension of GNOME shell using the terminal as I want to automate that which I can later use in my app. 
In the GUI version it is under "Position and Size" tab and then 'Panel Mode : extend to the screen edge'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the current value, run

```
gsettings get org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock extend-height
```

To change it, run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock extend-height <OPTION>
```

or

```
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/extend-height <OPTION>
```

In place of `<OPTION>` you can have `true` for panel mode and `false` for dock mode.

Comment: can you tell me how to make it permanent as it reverts back to default after Restart

Comment: It shouldn't, there's something wrong with your installation. I think that's why `gsettings` is not working.

Comment: @HarshKhatri Maybe you should ask a new question for that issue. If you do please provide details like your OS version, GNOME shell version, how you installed Dash to Dock etc. Hopefully someone will be able to help.